# disabling all clicks for a short period after clicking a image

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using multiple images to create something like a virtual keyboard. I wish to add a short period of time after a image is clicked, where at the short period of time, all clicks on images are disabled. Does any1 knows how to do it? Here's my code for one of the images.

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding Path=PressAndRelease}" CommandParameter="Q" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}" Effect="{Binding}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Image Name="imgNormalQ" Source="/wa;com/Images/alp/q.png" Height="127"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="999"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="imgPressedQ" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Ok, because it seems like you could modify the `CanExecute` portion of your command to handle this part.

Comment: I'd also hazard a guess that you could apply whatever effect using a storyboard and that might help. Too hard to say at this point.

Comment: I using storyboard in this case, but I don't know how to write the code there so that my objective could be done. But my idea is, when I click the image, the image would stays for few seconds and disabling all my clicks on images. So is it possible to make changes to this line?
`<Image Name="imgNormalQ" Source="/wa;com/Images/alp/q.png" Height="127"/>`

Comment: Yea I'm not sure about the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

in Silverlight I have done this using [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx)

there is not much difference in WPF

### *edited*

I have created sample Storyboard to disabled WPF UIElement.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Border x:Name="MainContent">
            <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonPanel">
                <Button Width="100" Click="AnyButton_Click">Busy State 1</Button>
                <Button Width="100" Click="AnyButton_Click">Busy State 2</Button>
                <Button Width="100" Click="AnyButton_Click">Busy State 3</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BusyStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Ready" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Busy">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonPanel" 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled">
                                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Border>
        <Button Width="100" x:Name="ClearButton" Click="ClearButton_Click">Ready</Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

the VisualState named "Busy" will animate ButtonPanel.IsEnabled = false (at keytime=0)

here's basic code behind

```
private void AnyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(MainContent, "Busy", true);
}

private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(MainContent, "Ready", true);
}
```

PS. if you follow the MVVM. VisualStateManager responsible for View. it should be part of XAML not ViewModel

Comment: sorry @ai.farfa although l somehow understands ur code, but I don't know how to put ur code into my use.

Comment: Sorry to trouble u again. In my case, l'm not using Event Handler, here's my code behind:
`public void PressQ(string key)
{
    if (key == "P")
    {
        PressP("q");
        ReleaseKey();
    }
}`